# UIButton created programmatically but doesn't show up on view (addSubview was called)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

Have an `AppDelegate` and a `MainViewController`. 
In `MainViewController` the `UIButton` was created, `AppDelegate` sets a background image and should show it on `MainViewController`. That's pretty much it but I can't see the `UIButton`.

Just for alignment purpose I created an `IBOutlet` and connected the button in IB.

MainViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *searchBtn;
```

MainViewController.m

```
@synthesize searchBtn;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize mainVC;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ViewController > setup:
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.mainVC;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Buttons > Set background images:
    [self.mainVC.searchBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.mainVC.view addSubview:self.mainVC.searchBtn];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Was the button added to the view in IB (I don't see anywhere here where you created it in code)? ID so, you don't need to call addSubview, it's already there.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I did not add the button in IB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you don't need `IBOutlet` if you are creating it programmatically.

Second you probably want to move the creation of the button in `viewDidLoad` of your view controller rather than in your `AppDelegate`. It's your view controller's business.

Third you should probably `alloc init` your button if you create it programmatically:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
[button setBackgroundImage:someImage];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(something:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You should be adding buttons in your MainViewController class, not the AppDelegate first off.

You should also set the background of the view in MainViewController, not the AppDelegate.

It should look like this:

AppDelegate.m

@synthesize mainVC;

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ViewController > setup:
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.mainVC;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

In your MainViewController.m's viewDidLoad put this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Buttons > Set background images:
    [searchBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //If you adding the button in Interface Builder you don't need to add it again
    //[self.view addSubview:self.mainVC.searchBtn];
}
```